# Plotting and modeling text data with swarmplot on python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a csv file and i want to use seaborn library's swarmplot for plotting the relation between two of the selected columns.

This is a sample of 5 rows from the csv file that i am working with

```
    SeriesCode       Year                 DESCRIPTION
21  IC.FRM.CORR.ZS   YR2004 The sample was drawn from the manufacturing sector only.
38  SP.ADO.TFRT      YR2010 Interpolated using data for 2007 and 2012.  
10  SP.ADO.TFRT      YR2000 Interpolated using data for 1997 and 2002.  
18  IC.FRM.CORR.ZS   YR2003 The sample was drawn from the manufacturing sector only.
32  IC.TAX.METG      YR2007 The sample was drawn from the manufacturing sector only.    
28  SP.ADO.TFRT      YR2006 Interpolated using data for 2002 and 2007.
```

And i have this piece of code

```
import re
import pandas


df1=pandas.read_csv("./Jobs_csv/JobsSeries-Time.csv")
ifcz=df1[df1['SeriesCode'].str.contains("IC.FRM.CORR.ZS",flags=re.IGNORECASE,regex=True)].DESCRIPTION
ify=df1[df1['SeriesCode'].str.contains("IC.FRM.CORR.ZS",flags=re.IGNORECASE,regex=True)].Year
sb.swarmplot(x="ifcz", y="ify", data=df1)
```

But whenever i run it

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-3c5933ceba52> in <module>()
----> 1 sb.swarmplot(x="ifcz", y="ify", data=df1)

/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in swarmplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, dodge, orient, color, palette, size, edgecolor, linewidth, ax, **kwargs)
   2975 
   2976     plotter = _SwarmPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
-> 2977                             dodge, orient, color, palette)
   2978     if ax is None:
   2979         ax = plt.gca()

/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, dodge, orient, color, palette)
   1214                  dodge, orient, color, palette):
   1215         """Initialize the plotter."""
-> 1216         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
   1217         self.establish_colors(color, palette, 1)
   1218 

/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    150                 if isinstance(var, str):
    151                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(var)
--> 152                     raise ValueError(err)
    153 
    154             # Figure out the plotting orientation

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'ifcz'
```

I get these errors.I dont know why it gives this error or how i can fix it.And i have become unsure whether swarmplot is supposed to be used for this.If you think it's because swarmplot shouldnt be used, then can you name other plots to model this?

Comment: You don't have numerical variables. What would you like to plot - total count? Linear relation?

Comment: then which plot should i use?

Comment: I can't answer that question because I have no idea what you want to see

Comment: If you want to plot `ify` as a function of `ifcz`, I think what you want to do is `sb.swarmplot(x=ifcz, y=ify, data=df1)`.